FCM, devices stop receiving messages x hours / day
Background
I have an app that is available for Android, WearOS, Android TV, iOS and WatchOS. This app is using FCM to transmit data messages to linked devices. It does so through a server of mine (located somewhere in the cloud), all seems to work fine.
The Android TV version of the app only receives the data packages, processes them and display the results to the user. This app runs for days on end in the foreground like a kiosk-mode app. The app is used inside a temporarily inflatable sports dome, 4 months a year.
When I move two of the (on my network) tested Android TV, Google Chromecast HD to be precise, devices to a location where end users can actually use it, then I run into issues.
Issue
On my local wired network, it runs fine for days and weeks on end. When the devices are on the new location, the FCM messages stop coming in after a few hours or a day or so. I haven't figured out the exact moment on how long this actually takes, but it seems to be within 24 hours. When I unplug the network cable, wait 10 seconds and reconnect it, the messages start coming in.
So it seems that it has something to do with the network.
Workaround
Last year I ran into the same issue and I couldn't figure out what was wrong. So I ended up buying and installing 4G LTE routers to which the Google Chromecasts were connected to (wired). Each device had it's own 4G LTE router and all was working just fine.
But these 4G routers cost additional money each month and it should work on the local available network.
Picture of local network
The sports dome has it's own Cisco switch. This switch is connected through a glass fiber connection to the main building. In the main building the receiving Cisco switch is connected to a ubiquiti unifi security gateway (USG), which in turn is connected to the modem / router of the local internet cable provider (this can't be set in bridge mode). The network is configured externally and has several VLAN's. There are no other network issues encoutered / present.
Another note to make is that the Google Chromecast's UTP cable in the sport dome is about 60 meters away from the switch and runs past some other (power) cables. At the end of the Chromecast the excess of the UTP cable is rolled up (appox. 10m). When performing updates on the Chromecast, the network works just fine. The cable is also tested with a Pockethernet cable tester -> no issues found.
Recap
So there are now three tested scenarios where only one seems to work:

devices linked to local network -> not working
devices linked to the UTP cables, but instead connected to the first Cisco switch to one 4G LTE router (with a very small 2-port switch in between https://www.amazon.nl/AVNSCNK-Ethernet-2-poorts-netwerkswitch-netwerksplitter/dp/B0CP77C225) -> not working
devices linked to a 4G LTE modem each directly -> working

When the devices are not working I can unplug and re-plug the network and then it seems to work again for a while. Not sustainable, but it indicates to me that FCM is loosing it's connection somehow.
In this setup it's very hard for me to debug etc. People are actually using it. So I have to revert back to option #3 again. On all of my other devices and app versions I don't experience any issue like this.
Is there anyone that has a clue on what could be the problem here?
=====
Update: I was too quick on my conclusion for scenario #2 mentioned above. This does work correctly.

you should check te documentation of FCM about this problem. I have this problem now but i resolve modify my request to FCM. Parameters as "priority" help me to solve this problem. To android i used proxy and priority to
 mensaje = {
            "GCM": json.dumps({
                "notification": {
                    "title": title,
                    "body": body.strip(),
                    "icon": "ic_launcher_round",
                    "android_channel_id": ChannelName,
                    "proxy":"DENY",
                    "notification_priority":"PRIORITY_MAX"
                },
                "data": {
                    "Alarmas": TextoAlarma,
                    "Fallas": TextoFalla,
                    "Superv": TextoSupervision,
                    "android_channel_id": ChannelName
                },
                "android": {
                    "priority":"HIGH"
                }
            })
        }

Docs FCM to solve this problem

The proxy attribute is new to me. I appreciate your reply, but I still really feel it is a network issue.
